# Prevent checkbox values from shifting after page reload on form submission

Tags: javascript, php, forms, checkbox

I have created a form which reloads in case of an error and goes to some other page in case of successful submission.

I don't want users to fill all values again and again in case of error so I store them in session variables and fill them back in the form.

Here is the HTML of the form:

```
<form action="preference.php" method="post">
<input id="optiona-cb" name="userpref[]" type="checkbox" value="optiona" <?php if((isset($_SESSION['userpref'][0]) && $_SESSION['userpref'][0])) { echo 'checked'; } ?>/>
<label for="optiona-cb">optiona</label>
<input id="optionb-cb" name="userpref[]" type="checkbox" value="optionb" <?php if((isset($_SESSION['userpref'][1]) && $_SESSION['userpref'][1])) { echo 'checked'; } ?>/>
<label for="optionb-cb">optionb</label>
<input id="optionc-cb" name="userpref[]" type="checkbox" value="optionc" <?php if((isset($_SESSION['userpref'][2]) && $_SESSION['userpref'][2])) { echo 'checked'; } ?>/>
<label for="optionc-cb">optionc</label>
... More Input Fields
</form>
```

Here is code from `preference.php`:

```
$_SESSION['userpref'] = $_POST['userpref'];
$_SESSION['user_login'] = $_POST['user_login'];
$_SESSION['user_email'] = $_POST['user_email'];
.. More code
```

On page reload, the `username` and `email` values are filled correctly. However, the checkbox values shift. For example, if a user only checks `optionc`, the value `optiona` gets checked on reload. Similarly, if a user checks `optiona` and `optionc`, the values `optiona` and `optionb` get checked.

In other words, "holes" in the ticked checkboxes get filled on page reload. How can I make sure that the checkbox values don't shift to fill empty values?

I am using WordPress if that matters. :)

Some Clarification:

The checkbox values are stored in `userpref[]` and accessed using `$_POST['userpref']`. I have no idea how a browser passes information about a checked checkbox using `$_POST`.

Let's say users checks the first and third checkbox. Also assume that `userpref[]` stores `1` for each checked checkbox and `0` for each unchecked checkbox. In this case, the value would be [1, 0, 1].

Once, I store these values in `$_SESSION['userpref']`, they seem to shift. In other words, the array becomes something like [1, 1, 0] or like [1, 1] and no third value implies unchecked checkbox.

So, instead of checking the first and third checkbox on reload. The browser checks the first and second. The third checkbox remains unchecked.

My question is, what can I do to make sure that the checkboxes retain their check uncheck status and it does not shift to fill the "holes" or "0"s.

Comment: event.preventDefault()
|
edit: Oh, nvm I misread. That will likely not help sorry.

Comment: Checkboxes are only submitted to PHP if they are actually checked. This info should explain your issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly that's what I relied on to properly check the checkboxes on reload. I will add more explanation in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test your values like this:

```
<input id="optiona-cb" name="userpref[]" type="checkbox" value="optiona" 
  <?php if (in_array('optiona', $_SESSION['userpref'])) echo 'checked' ?> />
```

**Explanation**:

You cannot rely on numeric indexes such as `[0]` or `[1]` because, as you noticed (and as someone commented), only checked boxes will be sent to the server. So for instance, if the first one isn't checked but the second is, `$_SESSION['userpref'][0]` will refer to the second one (because it's the first one checked).

Comment: Thanks @Jeto. :) That's what I ended up doing after reading some articles. Your explanation made it clearer. The comment was still confusing (maybe it is not worded properly).

Answer (score 0):

I think `userpref` abc => 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111 (8 things)

you should submit `userpref` optiona+optionb+optionc => "abc" such as "010"

so, I think that you use

```
substr($_POST['userpref'], 0, 1), 
substr($_POST['userpref'], 1, 1),
substr($_POST['userpref'], 2, 1)
```

you can this.

```
<input id="userpref" name="userpref" type="hidden" />
handleSubmit() {
    //...

    const a = $("#optiona").prop("checked") ? "1" : "0";
    const b = $("#optionb").prop("checked") ? "1" : "0";
    const c = $("#optionc").prop("checked") ? "1" : "0";
    $("#userpref").val(a+b+c);

    //...
    window.document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to get the respective "on/off" of the checkboxes based on the index as they are submitted from the browser. So, what happens when you only select checkbox index 0 and 2? Only those 2 will be submitted, something like `userpref[]=optiona&userpref[]=optionc` and now you only have 2 positions in the array, then the first 2 checkboxes will be selected!

Basically, it's not a correct match, so you should instead validate based on the checkboxes values.

Another point to make is that if none of the checkboxes are selected the following line is going to be a problem `$_SESSION['userpref'] = $_POST['userpref'];`.

Good luck!!

Comment: Hey @daniel. :) Wouldn't `$_POST['userpref']` and therefore `$_SESSION['userpref']` just be empty if there are no checkboxes selected?

Comment: Thanks @daniel. :)

Comment: Hi @Noobie, the value returned to `$_SESSION['userpref']` is going to be NULL but because you are accessing an unset key, a notice will be raised, not a big deal here, but I'd avoid that. I'd suggest you check `$_POST['userpref']` to see if it's set and if it isn't, just set `$_SESSION['userpref']` as an empty array, this way later on if you decide to loop all items, you won't get errors for trying to do it on a NULL value.